# Edit/Extract FLA files under linux?

Tags: linux, flash

I need to extract some content which is packed in fla or swf. It's some text which i need to grab. Is there any easy practical way to do that?

I tried http://freshmeat.net/projects/f4l/ and http://qflash.sourceforge.net but first has some problems with qt3 libs and second seems to throw some error in build which i can't fix :(

Comment: Under Linux you can install swftools (apt-get install swftools in Ubuntu) to extract contents.